# how to disable yellow pop-ups in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

[image]

They are annoying. They don't allow me to see the code. Maybe they are called tool-tips. I've already disabled all pop-ups in file/settings in Pycharm. I don't know where to find this feature shown in the picture and how to disable it.

Comment: Are they only when you mouse over it?

Comment: when I copy/paste something, this yellow pop-up also appears.When I mouse over it, it is also visible.

Comment: I wanted to paste some text in this place, and this yellow thing appeared instantly.

Comment: It looks like they can not be disabled: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114803

Comment: Try to push `Esc` button